# nodemon gives the error Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000 each time it starts automatically

Tags: nodemon

Which requires me to manually find the pid and kill it using `sudo kill -9 xxxxx`and then start nodemon again. Why is there another application running on port 5000, and how can I make sure that it doesn't?

Comment: It's going to be very difficult to tell you that without much more information. A starting point might be finding out *what* application is using that port, using e.g. `lsof -i :5000`.

Comment: The "NAME" of the application that I have to kill is always this: *:commplex-main (LISTEN)